# Random row from matrix with row number Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, matrix, numbers, row

How to pick a random row from a matrix in *Matlab*, and also row number of picked row?
I'v a matrix named `M` of `4x3` is following:

```
  -21.8318   19.2251  -16.0000
   -6.2788    8.6988  -10.0000
    1.5553   -0.8041   -2.0000
   17.6843  -13.0848    0.3000
```

My question is simple to pick a random row from matrix `M` (which is ofcourse, not a big deal) with its row number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `randi` to generate a random integer between `1` and the number of rows of `M`, and then use it to index into `M`:

```
ind = randi(size(M,1)); %// row number
row = M(ind,:); %// corresponding row
```